# Can you use Fourier transformations (or other) to read multiple superimposed barcodes?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform

If you printed bar codes on tracing paper/acetate etc. and then positioned several in front of one another, could you extract the individual codes from the aggregate overlaid image? I feel intuitively like there would be a limit on this, as given enough bar codes, the aggregate image would be plain black. It would be good to understand if this is possible in any circumstances and if so, what are the mathematical limits.

[image: Super Imposed Bar codes]

Thanks.

Comment: This is not really a physics question. It would probably fit better on [DSP SE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Whether this is possible depends on how you encode information into bar patterns, not on anything to do with physics.

Comment: To tie this question back to Physics, you should investigate [holographic data storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_data_storage). In this technique the fourier transform of an image (rather than just the original image) is stored in the storage medium. Using a [volume hologram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_hologram) you can arrange that a different image is reconstructed if you probe the hologram with a laser beam incident from different angles.

Answer (score 0):

So you're hoping that by measuring the gray level you can tell which bar belongs to which layer? That's potentially possible, but the problem is that a black bar on the top level completely masks any black or white bar on levels below, so there is no way to read all the barcodes. you might be able to reject the lower layers (read just the top) on the basis of gray scale. –

Comment: That's what I was thinking. What about if the printing was translucent?

Answer (score 0):

If black is absolute black, the top bar completely masks bars underneath. If the second layer also uses absolute black, it looks just like the top layer. So you wouldn't be able to discriminate.

If you have translucent grey bars, you cannot tell the difference between white-over-black and black-over-white.

If you had two layers where one was vertical and the other horizontal, you could read them both.

In general if you have multiple layers with shades of grey, you are trying to solve the same problem that physicians have when x-raying the human body. Everything lies on top of everything. You can recognize distinctive features like bones, which are equivalent to dark grey barcodes. But it can be hard to see detail in the white or light grey barcodes.

The solution is a CAT scan, where many x-rays are taken from different angles. From this, a 3D reconstruction of the body can be made. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CT_scan

Comment: What about if the bar codes aren't lined up, but are all at a random orientation and angle? Is there a way of identifying each unique string (bar code), by its reflected orientation. Not sure how you would be able to sense this though?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards, if you could guarantee that each pattern has a different angle, and the patterns are large enough to distinguish very near angles (e.g. to distinguish $90^\circ$ from $91^\circ$), then this would likely work.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for your answer. If we assume those conditions to have been met, how would you filter out each data string, based on differing angles?

Comment: A brute force way would take the 2-d fourier transform, take a slice through it at the angle of interest and reject other data, then inverse transform to recover the original data.

Comment: @ThePhoton when you say "slice through it at the angle of interest", what do you mean mathematically?

Comment: You'd apply a $\Pi(\omega_y)$ filter rotated to select the angle of interested. I'm just sketching a solution; getting it to really work will require a great deal of experimentation in Matlab/Scilab/Numpy/Octave.

Comment: @ThePhoton Great, I look forward to reading the solution.